# Correlation between two variables as time series with multiple samples

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, cross-correlation

#### Main objective

I have two variables ($A$ and $B$) as two time series for $n$ samples, and I would like to test if $A$ and $B$ are correlated. Let's first assume that these $n$ samples are independent to each other.

---

#### Description and questions

Essentially, for sample $i$ I have two paired time series: $\mathbf{a}_i = [a_{i,1}, a_{i,2}, \dots, a_{i,T_i}]$ and $\mathbf{b}_i = [b_{i,1}, b_{i,2}, \dots, b_{i,T_i}]$. Each sample always has its said two series of the same length $T_i$; but across samples the number of observations varies (i.e., $T_i$ varies for different $i$).

**Q1**: I could compute Pearson's $r$ for each sample, and end up with $n$ $r$'s (correlation coefficients). For the next step, is it reasonable to perform a test with the null hypothesis $H_0: r=0$? If so, what would be the appropriate test statistics? Could I use **one sample t-test** (one-sided, $H_1: r > 0$) here?

**Q2**: Since these are time series, should I be worrying and removing the *trend* before my analysis? Could I differentiate the time series and repeat the analysis mentioned in Q1? (i.e., looking at distribution of pairwise Pearson's $r$ across the samples.)

**Q3**: I also have similar datasets of other conditions as controls, where either the signal of $A$ or of $B$ is considered as *background*. (See more on detail below...) Could I instead having the null hypothesis $H_0: r_{\rm{exp-condition}} = r_{\rm{control-condition}}$ for each control condition that I have? (But I don't have same amount of samples for each condition; although they won't be paired anyway in the first place since each sample can only take one condition.) Should I perform a **two-sample t-test** with unequal sample size and unequal variance (Welch t-test)?

---

#### More detail...

This is a microscopy dataset (multi-channel confocal fluorescence images) which looks at live biological samples. The real question to ask here is: if the amount of an underlying object (molecule) $\alpha$ correlates the amount of another underlying molecule $\beta$. This would partially help us investigating our working model where molecule $\alpha$ helps the generation of molecule $\beta$, but only when $\beta$ already exists (and being above some concentration).

The value of variable $A$ reflects the quantity of said underlying molecule $\alpha$ at the region where the data was taken; same thing goes for $B$ and $\beta$. And for each type of molecule, there is a threshold value below which we can't tell the difference between *some $\alpha$ exist* vs. *$\alpha$ doesn't exist* -- this is what I meant by *background* in Q3, and we usually consider the number of $\alpha$ is negligible when the value of $A$ is below that threshold.

In our experiment, if there is $\alpha$, we could perturb the sample and make it more $\alpha$ within the region observed. So there should be a trend of increasing number of $\alpha$ (thus increasing value of $A$). However, I guess there could be other time-dependent factors that contribute to the overall trend, so that's why I was trying to look at the differentiated form before computing pairwise correlation coefficient (Q2).

We make measurements (e.g., pixel-intensity from channel A and channel B, averaged over a region of sample -- can just be thought of as some way to measure how many $\alpha$ and $\beta$ molecules are there) for a sample over a period of time, over which two time series ($\mathbf{a}_i$ and $\mathbf{b}_i$) for sample $i$ are recorded. The said procedure is repeated several times to generate the full dataset.

**Q4**: And here is one last point to make the analysis a bit more complex -- instead of measuring a single sample at a time (*yes*, I lied in the previous paragraph...), several samples could be measured simultaneously. It's not too strong of an assumption to pretend that the $n$ samples are independent, but I would like to know if and how to take care of this aspect for the analysis, if some of the samples are not that independent.